# How to get an unique output in PHP from multiple Items and arrays

Tags: php, squid, whmcs

PHP isn't returning unique items between assigned_IPs and IP_array.
I need an unique output.

I already tried merging arrays and comparing them.

```
    $ips2 = array(); 

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {
        $ips2[] = $row["ipaddr"]; 
    } 
        $assigned_ips  = $ips2;

 $ip_array = explode("\n",$ips);

$ips_left = array_diff($ip_array,$assigned_ips);
```

I need to return an unique array once PHP compares the 2 item lists.

Answer (score 0):

Lucky for you, PHP has an [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function for just such a purpose!  You could perform it on both of the compared arrays before `array_diff()`, but I am pretty sure best (an most efficient) practice would be to perform it only once when you already have the results:

```
$ips2 = array(); 

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {
        $ips2[] = $row["ipaddr"]; 
    } 
$assigned_ips  = $ips2;

$ip_array = explode("\n",$ips);

$ips_left = array_unique(
    array_diff($ip_array,$assigned_ips)
);
```

Just for the sake of completeness, here is an alternative way that could be more efficient if you have a large number of duplicates that would bog down the `array_diff()` function:

```
$ips2 = array(); 

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {
        $ips2[] = $row["ipaddr"]; 
    } 
$assigned_ips  = $ips2;

$ip_array = explode("\n",$ips);

$ips_left = array_diff(
    array_unique($ip_array)
    array_unique($assigned_ips)
);
```

Comment: Duplicates decreased a lot but still exist, I'm trying to find the solution.

Comment: @MaruanAwad - I would guess that you have non-unique keys or a differently structured array for each of the two that you are comparing.  You can try using [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) when populating `$ips_left`.  Otherwise, I am going to need more information.  Specifically, sample values from the arrays that you are comparing.